# Ejecutar función en Select de oracle varias veces

Tags: oracle, subconsultas

tengo una consulta en Oracle que llama a una función "***dias_trabajados(fechainici, fechafin, usuario, unidad)***" os pongo la consulta:

```
Select age.txdescripcion As agencia, usr.txnombre As usuario,
    MIN(DIAS_TRABAJADOS(TO_DATE('01/01/2016'), TO_DATE('31/12/2016'), txnombre, usr.txcodigoagencia)) AS diast, 
    SUM(vmr.pvp) AS pvp, SUM(vmr.rent) AS rent, ROUND(CASE WHEN SUM(vmr.rent) <> 0 THEN (SUM(vmr.rent)*100)/SUM(vmr.pvp) ELSE 0 END,2) AS prent
    ,MIN(ROUND((vce.importeanual + vcess.importeanual) * (DIAS_TRABAJADOS(TO_DATE('01/01/2016'), TO_DATE('31/12/2016'), txnombre, usr.txcodigoagencia))/365,2) ) as cempresa
FROM vacacional_usuarios_view usr 
    INNER JOIN vacacional_agencias_view age ON usr.TXCODIGOAGENCIA = age.TXCODIGOAGENCIA 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN MVD_TINF_RETRIBUCION vmr ON usr.TXCODIGOAGENCIA = vmr.TXCODIGOAGENCIA And usr.TXCODIGOUSUARIO=vmr.TXCODIGOUSUARIO And vmr.FECHA BETWEEN '01/01/2016' AND '31/12/2016' 
    INNER JOIN vacacional_costeempresa_view vce ON usr.TXCODIGOAGENCIA=vce.TXCODIGOAGENCIA AND usr.TXCODIGOUSUARIO=vce.TXCODIGOUSUARIO AND vce.FECHA_INICIO BETWEEN '01/01/2016' AND '31/12/2016' 
    INNER JOIN vacacional_costeempresass_view vcess ON usr.TXCODIGOAGENCIA=vcess.TXCODIGOAGENCIA AND usr.TXCODIGOUSUARIO=vcess.TXCODIGOUSUARIO AND vcess.FECHA_INICIO BETWEEN '01/01/2016' AND '31/12/2016'
WHERE (fechabaja IS NULL OR fechabaja >='01/01/2016') AND fechaalta <= '31/12/2016' AND age.txdescripcion = NOMBRE_DE_LA_UNIDAD 
GROUP BY age.txdescripcion, usr.txnombre
ORDER BY age.txdescripcion, usr.txnombre;
```

Como se puede ver llamo 2 veces a la funcion

> DIAS_TRABAJADOS(TO_DATE('01/01/2016'), TO_DATE('31/12/2016'), txnombre, usr.txcodigoagencia))

esta es la función dias_trabajados():

```
    create or replace FUNCTION DIAS_TRABAJADOS(fecha_inicio IN DATE, fecha_fin IN DATE, usuario IN STRING, agencia IN STRING)
  RETURN NUMBER IS
    numero_dias NUMBER := 0;
    falta DATE;
    fbaja DATE;
    CURSOR usuarios IS 
        SELECT txcodigousuario, txcodigoagencia, 
            CASE WHEN fechaalta <= fecha_inicio THEN fecha_inicio ELSE fechaalta END AS fechaalta, 
            CASE WHEN fechabaja Is NULL THEN fecha_fin  WHEN fechabaja >= fecha_fin THEN fecha_fin ELSE fechabaja END AS fechabaja
        FROM USUARIOS_VIEW
        WHERE txcodigoagencia = agencia AND txnombre = usuario AND (fechabaja is null OR fechabaja >= fecha_inicio) AND fechaalta <= fecha_fin
        GROUP BY txcodigousuario, txcodigoagencia, fechaalta, fechabaja
         ORDER BY fechaalta;
    rst usuarios%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    FOR rst IN usuarios LOOP      
      numero_dias := numero_dias + ((rst.fechabaja - rst.fechaalta)+1);
    END LOOP;
    IF ANIOBISIESTO(fecha_inicio) = 1 THEN
        IF FEBREROBISIESTO(fecha_inicio, fecha_fin) = 1 THEN numero_dias := numero_dias -1; END IF;     --evalua si hay febrero dentro del bisiesto
        IF numero_dias > 365 THEN numero_dias :=365; END IF;        --caso de ser todo el año bisiesto solo devuelve 365 dias     
    END IF;

    return numero_dias;
 END DIAS_TRABAJADOS;
```

el objeto de la función dias_trabajados es diferenciar el total de dias por año caso de ser bisiesto o no ya que siempre vamos a trabajar sobre la base de 365 
días, y caso valida si entre fechas hay un febrero o no, el caso es que para obtener al final 15 registros tarda 1'35" y no se si se puede conservar el valor de una función en la misma linea de la select sin tener que ejecutarla en cada columna que la necesites. Aprovecho para preguntar si alguien cree que esta consulta se puede optimizar?
Los valores de fechas son dinámicos ya que provienen de un formulario de vb.net.
de antemano muchas gracias por cualquier respuesta o aportación.

Comment: Lamento decirte que no estás llamando dos veces `DIAS_TRABAJADOS`, sino que lo estas haciendo dos veces por cada fila, y encima es una función con un cursor, es totalmente entendible que la performance no sea buena. Por otro lado hay algo que no entiendo, en la función estas retornando la cantidad de días entre dos fechas luego tomas la diferencia en días y las vas sumando en el cursor, por que haces eso? un usuario/agencia puede tener múltiples fecha_inicio, fecha_fin? Y por otro lado por que no usas las rutinas de diferencias de días de Oracle que ya contemplan años bisiestos?

Comment: ¿cual es la rutina de oracle que contempla años bisiestos? los usuarios pueden moverse entre unidades varias veces en el mismo año por eso necesito saber los dias trabajados en un periodo determinado en una unidad, ah muy importante en caso de ser año bisiesto solo quiero tratarlo como 365dias

Comment: La resta de fecha habitual da la cantidad de días, esos días contemplan el año bisisto en la suma de días. Lo que dices es que un usuario puede tener varios registros en el cursor, que si uno de esos períodos entró un 29 de febrero le tienes que restar un día, y lo que buscas es la suma total de esos días?

Comment: Correcto @PatricioMoracho, pero voy a cerrar este hilo ya que voy a abrir otro, debido a que haciendo las pruebas sin añadir ningún inner join a la select y ejecutando dias_trabajados la select responde de forma immediata, ahora mi necesidad es una vez obtenido los días trabajados, quiero aprovecharlos en el resto de columnas que hay en la consulta y por lo que he podido leer pinta que voy a tener que mirar el tema de 'execute immediate' para crear una vista parametrizada, uff otro frente, esto es un no acabar nunca. muchas gracias por tu atención.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cierro el hilo ya que resolví el problema por medio de crear **porcedures** para crear vistas dinamicas mediante el `execute immediate`.
gracias